# Comparing two probabilties related to the sample mean

Tags: probability

> A probability density function $f(x)$ has following properties:
>
> 1. $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$;
> 2. $f$ is decreasing on $[0,+∞)$.
>
> Let $X_1, \cdots, X_n, X_{n + 1}$ be a random sample from $f(x)$ population and define $\displaystyle \overline{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n X_k$. Given a constant $c > 0$, compare $P(|\overline{X}| \leqslant c)$ and $P(|X_{n + 1} - \overline{X}| \leqslant c)$.

Intuitively, there seems to be $P(|\overline{X}| \leqslant c) \geqslant P(|X_{n + 1} - \overline{X}| \leqslant c)$. If $E(X_k)$ exists, it equals $0$. So $P(|\overline{X}| \leqslant c)$ indicates the deviation of the sample mean from the expectation. Since $X_k$ is "concentrated" around $0$ and $\overline{X}$ is more concentrated around $0$ than $X_{n + 1}$, then$$
P(|X_{n + 1} - \overline{X}| \leqslant c) \approx P(|X_{n + 1}| \leqslant c) \leqslant P(|\overline{X}| \leqslant c).
$$

Above is my thought, but I failed to get a rigorous proof since I have no idea how to compute $P(|X_{n + 1} - \overline{X}| \leqslant c)$. Any help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that the distribution of $\overline X$ is also absolutely continuous, symmetric and unimodal due to [Wintner's Theorem](https://books.google.ru/books?id=V3rNCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=due%20to%20Wintner%20(1938)&source=bl&ots=VHJW_6E3sj&sig=fngdZ31yRVLZW8cY3fUieyWi3Ok&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6zOKwv7nYAhUKApoKHYRRAVMQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=due%20to%20Wintner%20(1938)&f=false)

*The convolution of two symmetric unimodal distributions on $\mathbb R$ is unimodal.*

Then for any positive $c$ and for any $y$
$$
\mathbb P(|\overline X-y|\leqslant c) \leqslant \mathbb P(|\overline X|\leqslant c).
$$
Using independence of $\overline X$ and $X_{n+1}$, fix the value of $X_{n+1}=y$ and integrate over $y$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(|\overline{X}-X_{n+1}|\leqslant c) =  &\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbb P\left(|\overline{X}-y|\leqslant c\right) f(y)\,dy  \leqslant \cr 
& \int_{\mathbb R}\mathbb P\left(|\overline{X}|\leqslant c\right) f(y)\,dy =  \mathbb P\left(|\overline{X}|\leqslant c\right).
\end{align}

Comment: I do not believe that unimodality is sufficient for the inequality; I think we need symmetry as well (and indeed the convolution of two symmetric, unimodal distributions is unimodal *and* symmetric). The citation for Wintner's Theorem is very close to a typo in that book when it says, "A distribution $F$ on $R$ is symmetric unimodal if, and only if, for every $\delta\gt0$, the function $$g(x)=F(x+\delta)-F(x+\delta)$$ is symmetric unimodal." By that definition $g(x)=0$ and therefore, no $F$ would be symmetric unimodal. I believe that they wanted $$g(x)=F(x+\delta)+F(x-\delta)$$

Comment: @robjohn The symmetry of a distribution of sample mean is stated in the very first string. It follows trivially from the symmetry of the sample distributions. In Wintner's theorem, a nontrivial fact is proved - the unimodality of the distribution. The symmetry of the distribution is obvious and there is no need to make it the subject of this theorem. So this is not a typo.

Comment: My comment was on the statement "The convolution of two symmetric unimodal distributions on $\mathbb{R}$ is unimodal." However, applying that alone is insufficient, whether the result is actually symmetric (which it is) or not. If the statement was "The convolution of two symmetric unimodal distributions on $\mathbb{R}$ is symmetric unimodal.", *that* would be sufficient. I mentioned the typo in the book only as a side remark.

Comment: @robjohn Again, the statement of the mentioned theorem does not contain a typo. The nontrivial fact proved in the theorem is unimodality. The symmetry follows directly and is not the subject of the theorem.

Comment: I never said that the statement of the theorem contained a typo. I said: "The citation for Wintner's Theorem is very close to a typo in that book". It is the Corollary that contains the typo. In any case, as I said, that is a side remark.